# Drawing and displaying rectangle every 3 seconds in opencv : C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to draw and display rectangles every `3 Sec`

The code I have come up is as below:

```
vector <Rect> ROI;

    for (size_t i = 0; i< ROI.size(); i++)
        {
        rectangle(src, ROI[i].tl(), ROI[i].br(), Scalar(110, 220, 0), 10, 8, 0);
        imshow(source_window, src);

        const std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>threadSuspendDuration_k(3000);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(threadSuspendDuration_k);

    }
```

When I draw rectangles then call `imshow` i.e. outside the for loop, it works fine.

But when `imshow` is inside the for loop, I expect rectangle to be drawn and shown every 3 seconds. But it does not.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You did not read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow), specifically the note about `waitKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `cv::waitKey` for delay.

```
vector <Rect> ROI;

    for (size_t i = 0; i< ROI.size(); i++)
     {
        rectangle(src, ROI[i].tl(), ROI[i].br(), Scalar(110, 220, 0), 10, 8, 0);
        imshow(source_window, src);
        waitKey(3000);//3 seconds delay
    }
```